# RAM strangeness on brand new ASUS K55N

Tags: windows-8, memory, bios

Not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange site, but I bought a brand new ASUS K55N laptop (6 GB RAM) but it says only 1.46 GB is usable.  Info:

- Windows 8.0 x64
- System reports 6 GB but only 1.46 usable
- msconfig Boot tab does NOT have memory checked in advanced options
- BIOS reports 2018 GB RAM
- Called ASUS, apparently this model has 1 2 GB stick and 1 4 GB stick

  - This led me to believe that the 4 GB stick was corrupt but I ran the Windows memory diagnostic utility and came back with no errors.

Any thoughts? Other things I should try?

UPDATE:

- Just saw that it has 4 GB as hardware reserved! That can't be right? How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you check the BIOS settings? Also, try removing one of the RAM stick and test it on the both slots. Then repeat the same procedure for the other stick.

Comment: Well so I opened up the laptop and it has the 2 GB on top and the 4 GB on bottom.  I switched them, and when I rebooted it now said 6 GB (3.7 available).  This tells me that the actual physical bottom RAM slot is defective, as whatever is in it is not usable. Anyone agree?